# Unable to get package name of chosen third party app with PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE

Tags: android, kotlin, broadcastreceiver

I need to get the name of the app chosen by user fired with `Intent.ACTION_SEND` for analytic purposes. The name of app will be obtained through `BroadcastReceiver`.

It works until one day, the security engineer in our team informed us that all `PendingIntent` in the codebase must have `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` to be secure.

The flag added breaks the existing functionality because `intent?.getParcelableExtra<ComponentName>(Intent.EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT)?.packageName` will always return null.

Is there anything I can do? `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` is sadly not an option for me.

You can find same way of doing this from [Android Documentation - Getting information about sharing](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#share-interaction-data)

**MainActivity.kt**

```
const val PENDING_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE = 0x1000
const val THIRD_PARTY_SHARE_REQUEST_CODE = 0x1001
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        btnShare.setOnClickListener {
            openThirdPartyShareDialog()
        }
    }

    private fun openThirdPartyShareDialog() {
        val thirdPartyShareIntent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            type = "text/plain"
        }

        val broadcastIntent = Intent(this, ThirdPartyAppBroadcastReceiver::class.java)

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
            PENDING_INTENT_REQUEST_CODE,
            broadcastIntent,
            getPendingFlagIntent()
        )

        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(
            thirdPartyShareIntent,
            null,
            pendingIntent.intentSender
        ), THIRD_PARTY_SHARE_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    private fun getPendingFlagIntent(): Int {
        var flags = PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            flags = flags or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        }
        return flags
    }
}
```

**ThirdPartyAppBroadcastReceiver.kt**

```
class ThirdPartyAppBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    // packageName will always be null !
        val packageName =
            intent?.getParcelableExtra<ComponentName>(Intent.EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT)?.packageName 
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.flamyoad.broadcast_share"
    >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Broadcastshare"
        >
        <receiver android:name="com.flamyoad.broadcast_share.ThirdPartyAppBroadcastReceiver" />
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

Turns out it's fine to remove `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` if you're using explicit intent.

> Android apps send messages between components using Intents. Intents
> can either specify the target component (Explicit Intent) or list a
> general action and let the operating system deliver the Intent to any
> component on the device that registers an Intent Filter matching that
> action (Implicit Intent).
>
> PendingIntents are Intents delegated to another app to be delivered at
> some future time. Creating an implicit intent wrapped under a
> PendingIntent is a security vulnerability that might lead to
> denial-of-service, private data theft, and privilege escalation.

You can read more about it from [Remediation for Implicit PendingIntent Vulnerability](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10437428?hl=en)